# I have created a new project with ANGULAR 12, I am trying to add Jest.js to

Tags: jestjs, angular12

### I have created a new project with ANGULAR 12, I am trying to add Jest.js to this project, but I get the next error.

```
    TypeError: Jest: a transform must export something.
    at D:\Refraccion\SOFTWARE----\TDD and DBB\demo1\node_modules\@jest\transform\build\ScriptTransformer.js:386:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ScriptTransformer.loadTransformers (D:\Refraccion\SOFTWARE----\TDD and DBB\demo1\node_modules\@jest\transform\build\ScriptTransformer.js:378:5)
    at async createScriptTransformer (D:\Refraccion\SOFTWARE----\TDD and DBB\demo1\node_modules\@jest\transform\build\ScriptTransformer.js:1106:3)
    at async D:\Refraccion\SOFTWARE----\TDD and DBB\demo1\node_modules\@jest\core\build\TestScheduler.js:269:31
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async TestScheduler.scheduleTests (D:\Refraccion\SOFTWARE----\TDD and DBB\demo1\node_modules\@jest\core\build\TestScheduler.js:262:5)
    at async runJest (D:\Refraccion\SOFTWARE----\TDD and DBB\demo1\node_modules\@jest\core\build\runJest.js:387:19)
    at async _run10000 (D:\Refraccion\SOFTWARE----\TDD and DBB\demo1\node_modules\@jest\core\build\cli\index.js:408:7)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! demo1@0.0.0 test: `jest`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the demo1@0.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-06T22_50_07_345Z-debug.log
```

---

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@core/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/app/core/$1',
  },
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
};
```

---

package.json

```
{
  "name": "demo1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "jest",

  }
}
```

Is there some way to fix it in ANGULAR?

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same thing when I tried to create a new project, so far it isn't compatible with the newest Angular 12 yet that I know of.